# Interacting Hamiltonian commutes with momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In Peskin's textbook chapter 7 Radiative Corrections: some formal developments (page 212 second paragraph), he describes two-point functions and chooses states to be eigenstates of the full interacting Hamiltonian $H$. Since the momentum operator $P$ commutes with $H$, we can also choose the states to be eigenstates of $P$.

So my question is how can an interacting Hamiltonian $H$ still commute with the total momentum operator $P$? In my mind, only a free system's Hamiltonian $H$ can commutes with $P$, so is there anything wrong? I am very confused by this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Heisenberg's equations of motion,
$$
[H,P]\propto \partial_t P
$$
which equals zero because $P$ is time-independent. This assumes nothing about the nature of $P,H$, (except for the fact that these generate translations). The system need not be free: the only thing you need is HEoM, which is one of the postulates of QM.

But how do we know that $\partial _tP=\partial _t H=0$? that is, how do we know that the generators are time-independent?

Well, for the Hamiltonian its fairly easy to see that $\partial_t H\propto [H,H]=0$, because ever operator commutes with itself. Therefore, $H$ is time independent. In the case of the momentum operator, the easiest way to see that $\partial_t P=0$ is to realise that $P^\mu$ is the Noether charge of $x^\mu\to x^\mu+a^\mu$, that is, $P^\mu$ is the generator of translations. In other words,
$$
P^\mu=\int\mathrm d\boldsymbol x\ T^{0\mu}
$$
where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the stress-energy tensor (the Noether current). Noether's theorem implies that charges are conserved, that is, $\partial_t P^\mu=0$.

Comment: But for an interacting Hamiltonian, even Hamiltonian is dependent on time, so how can momentum is conserved?

Comment: @Ben in interacting theories, the generators are always conserved, because they are the charges of Noether currents (by construction). This means that, both in free theories and in interacting theories, the energy, momentum, angular momentum, etc, are conserved. The same thing happens in classical mechanics: the (total) momentum is conserved both for free and for interacting systems.

Comment: @Ben An interacting Hamilton need not be time dependent. Consider for example the Hamiltonian for two electrons with a Coloumb repulsion with no external fields present. In this case, it is true that the individual electron momenta do not commute with H, but the total momentum still commutes with H since the Coloumb interaction commutes with the total momentum.

Answer (score 4):

The assumption is that momentum is conserved. So total momentum is a constant of motion. The operator for a constant of motion would commute with the Hamiltonian, because, being a constant of motion, its derivative with respect to time vanishes.